# Вызов конструктора из другого конструктора

Tags: java, ооп, конструктор

Так все работает:

```
public Triangle(Point2D point1, Point2D point2, Point2D point3, String color) throws ColorException {
    this(point1, point2, point3, Color.colorFromString(color));
}
```

А вот так,

```
public Triangle(Point2D point1, Point2D point2, Point2D point3, String color) throws ColorException {
    Color eColor = Color.colorFromString(color);
    this(point1, point2, point3, eColor);
}
```

возникает ошибка:

```
Error:(23, 13) java: call to this must be first statement in constructor
```

Из чего вытекает такое требование, и как его обойти?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1168415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое ограничение вытекает из ограничений JLS.

> Исторически `this()` или `super()` должно быть первым в конструкторе.
>   Это ограничение никогда не было популярным и воспринималось как
>   произвольное. Существовал ряд тонких причин, в том числе проверка
>   `invokespecial`, которые способствовали этому ограничению. На
>   протяжении многих лет мы рассматривали их на уровне VM, до того
>   момента, когда становится целесообразным рассмотреть возможность
>   отмены этого ограничения не только для записей, но и для всех
>   конструкторов.

---

По крайней мере вы будете знать порядок вызовов конструкторов в классах.

---

Как это можно обойти, ну скажем добавить код, который будет выполняться перед вызовом конструктора. В первом случае вы вызываете код при передаче параметра. Можно использовать `super()` вместо `this()` если придумать суперклас и использовать его конструктор. Можно также использовать вызов AOP интерсептора перед конструктором.