# Call to super must be first statement in constructor body

Tags: java, ооп

Друзья помогите разобраться, есть абстрактный класс `Animal`

```
public abstract class Animal {
boolean vegetarian;
String speak;
byte paws;

public Animal(boolean veg, String speak, byte paws) {
    this.vegetarian = veg;
    this.speak = speak;
    this.paws = paws;
}
}
```

Наследую от него класс `Cat`

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public void Cat() {
        super(false,"мяу",(byte)4);
    }
}
```

Хочу в super передать аргументы не указывая их при создании объекта. Получаю ошибку.

```
Call to super must be first statement in constructor body
```

Погуглил, говорят что super() должен идти первый в конструкторе, ну так вроде он первый идёт. В чём здесь проблема?

Comment: `public void Cat()`. `void`?

Comment: @PetSerAl мля, во я дибил)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов конструктора из другого конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890152/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо просто быть повнимательнее)

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
public Cat() {
    super(false,"мяу",(byte)4);
 }
}
```