# Создание объекта суперкласса в Java

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, конструктор

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему при создании объекта суперкласса вызывается конструктор подкласса и суперкласса?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Student();
// is Person
// is Student

    }
}

public class Person {
    Person(){
        System.out.println("is Person");
    }
}

public class Student extends Person{
    Student(){
        System.out.println("is Student");
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут вы создаете объект `Student`, т.е. объект подкласса, а не суперкласса. Так что вопрос некорректный. Нет здесь создания объекта суперкласса.

Answer (score 4):

Это называется цепочкой конструкторов (`constructor chaining`). Использование цепочки гарантирует, что все конструкторы суперклассов будут вызваны, начиная с конструктора класса, объект которого создается, и далее вверх по иерархии до класса `Object`.

В случае, если не был прописан вызов конструктора суперкласса, то компилятор подставит его [автоматически](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Ссылки на документацию по конструкторам:

- [Constructor Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)
- [Default Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

Answer (score 3):

Исходя из того, что вы присваиваете ссылочной переменной, которая имеет тип Person, объект Student это не означает что вы создали объект родительского класса, поэтому у вас и отрабатывают все конструкторы. У вас всего лишь тип ссылки Person, а она указывает на объект Student в куче, так как вы сами указали оператор new Student(). Это сделано для того, чтобы обеспечить полиморфизм, но это уже другая история. А создавая таким образом объект Student вы получаете доступ лишь к функциональности, унаследованной от класса Person. Так как компилятор интересует лишь тип ссылки, а не объект который ей присвоили, то вы не сможете вызывать методы класса Student.

**Немного теории**: значит смотрите, у вас есть объект класса Student, в момент его создания вызывается конструктор объекта, который как вы полагаете, создаете через оператор new (То есть отрабатывает конструктор класа Student). Вы все правильно подумали, но в вашем случае у вас Student является подклассом Person. В Java, если вы создаете объект самого нижнего в иерархии наследования класса, он обязан вызвать все родительские конструкторы в верх по цепочке наследования вплоть до класса Object (Так как все классы в Java наследуют его). Поэтому когда вы создаете подкласс Student, так как он унаследован от Person, Java, вызывая конструктор класса Student, автоматически сначала обратится к конструктору класса Person. Вы также можете сделать это явно, применив super();

```
public class Student extends Person {

   Student() {
     super(); // Java - сама позаботится о добавлении конструктора подкласса, поэтому вы не обязаны так писать, но можете.
   }

}
```

Исходя из примера мы видим, что для вызова конструктора класса Person Java использует некий super() - он и подразумевает вызов родительского конструктора.

**Немного подумаем**: И возникает вопрос - а зачем Java по умолчанию вызывает сначала конструктор класса Person, ведь меня особо не интересует что там. Там даже нет ни переменных, ни методов, тогда зачем? А теперь представьте, что у вас в родительском классе Person есть состояние, то есть определены переменные уровня экземпляра, и при этом все это наследует ваш класс Student. Как тогда в момент создания объекта Student мы сможем инициализировать переменные уровня экземпляра унаследованные от класса Person? То есть получается мы не сможет через конструктор сделать этого. Да, вы конечно можете вызвать методы get() и set(), но тогда какой толк вообще от конструктора?

Представьте что у вас Person имеет поля name и surname. Вы их наследуете и тут возникает момент когда во время создания класса Student необходимо инициализировать эти переменные, так вот Java и предоставляет вам эту возможность. Теперь то мы знаем, что инициализация в Java начинается от самого верха, (от Object) и заканчивая вашим подклассом.

Можете считать, что создавая объект подкласса, вы создаете комбинацию из всех родителей, которые идут вверх по цепочке. То есть один ваш объект включает в себя все родительские классы и вот поэтому необходимо вызывать все конструкторы входящих в список родительских классов для инициализации тех переменных, которые были получены от определенного родителя.

Старался как можно более доходчиво объяснить, но не особо силен в этом. Надеюсь мой ответ поможет вам :)
А так, предлагаю вам почитать K. Syerra - Изучаем Java. Она переведена на русский, поэтому проблем у вас не будет. Там все это очень-очень доходчиво объясняется, там вы найдете ответы на множество вопросов которые интересует всех новичков.

Answer (score 1):

При создании объекта класса вызывается его конструктор. Если создаётся объект подкласса, то вызывается его конструктор, который в свою очередь вызывает конструктор суперкласса.

Зачем это делается понять несложно, если думать о том, что при наследовании объект класса является также объектом суперкласса, то есть содержит в себе все переменные и методы суперкласса.

Получив объект суперкласса через создание его подкласса приводит к тому, что тип объекта в рантайме будет отличаться от типа при компиляции, а следовательно необходимо вызывать конструктор при создании объекта этого типа.

Вызов конструктора происходит по умолчанию если не используется ключевое слово `this` или `super`. Более подробно об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/890311/204920).

Ещё подробнее это описано в Java [тюториале](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html), где даётся этот материал с примерами.

> Конструкторы не являются членами, поэтому они не наследуются подклассами, но конструктор суперкласса *может* быть вызван из подкласса.

Главное, вы должны усвоить, что создание объекта определенного типа однозначно определяет вызов конструктора этого типа, который в свою очередь вызывает конструктор суперкласса. Этот вызов происходит неявно или явно с помощью `super`. Конструктор без аргументов, или если используется конструктор по умолчанию при создании объекта может вызываться неявно. Подробнее о конструкторах по умолчанию и конструкторе без аргументов можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/957278/204920).