# Зачем вообще нужно создавать конструктор, чтобы обратиться к полю?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, конструктор

Помогите понять.

Есть класс родителя, с полем:

```
public class Pet {    
    String name;    
}
```

Есть его наследник:

```
public class Cat extends Pet {
    private int age;
}
```

Почему, при создании объекта наследника я просто не могу указать поле родителя? Каким боком к полю наследника имеет отношение конструктор родителя?

То есть почему я просто не могу сделать так?

Конструктор наследника:

```
 public Cat(String name, int age) {
        super(name);
        this.age = age;
    }
```

Не создавая конструктор у родителя?

Ведь конструктор же, это по сути просто шаблон с какими полями нужно создать объект.

Comment: `шаблон с какими полями нужно создать объект` Нет. В конструктор можно передать параметры, анализируя которые он создаст объект. Совершенно необязательно параметры должны соответствовать полям, конструктор создаваемого объекта "принимает во внимание", "анализирует", "трансформирует" входные параметры, придавая полям нужные значения.

Comment: [Попробуйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1307787) поле `name` сделать protected: `protected String name`. Тогда из конструктора `Cat` вы сможете обратиться к этому полю `this.name = name`.

Comment: родитель НЕ шаблон. сначала вызывается конструктор родителя, затем уже дочерний конструктор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваше утверждение неверно:

> Ведь конструктор же, это по сути просто шаблон с какими полями нужно создать объект.

Конструктор вызывается при создании объекта, причем параметры конструктора не определяют с какими полями этот объект создается, а позволяют передать значения переменных в конструктор при его вызове. Эти значения выбираются произвольно, и независимо от полей класса наследника или его родителя. Просто если класс имеет поля, то в конструктор можно передать значения параметров, для того, чтобы *инициализировать* поля, или для других целей. Названия и количество параметров конструктора необязательно должны соответствовать полям. Если есть параметры, которые имеют названия такие же как названия полей, то для доступа к полям можно использовать ключевое слово `this`.

> Почему, при создании объекта наследника я просто не могу указать поле родителя?

При создании объекта наследника создаются все поля, включая родителя. Они создаются *инлайн* до вызовов конструкторов. Конструктора вызываются в определенном порядке, о котором можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1166142/204920).

Опять же, если вы думали, что можете указать поле родителя как параметр конструктора, то это неверно. Вам нужно понять, что создание объекта - это сложная процедура, которая производится в определенном порядке, и вызов конструкторов имеет свое место и время.

> Каким боком к полю наследника имеет отношение конструктор родителя?

Наверно вы думали, что с помощью конструктора наследника можно инициализировать поля родителя без вызова конструктора родителя. Это неверно. Для инициализации полей родителя можно вызвать конструктор родителя и передать значение поля с помощью `super()`. Я уже описал выше зачем нужно вызывать конструктор родителя, а к полю наследника действительно никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Роман, невероятно! Спасибо!!!!!!!

Comment: @ДядяФёдор Пожалуйста!!! Галочка напротив ответа поможет.

Answer (score 4):

В вашем примере всё довольно однозначно, но стоит его немного усложнить и становится непонятно что делать с данными:

```
public class Pet {    
    String name;    
    String alias;
}
```

Какой теперь конструктор должен быть? `name` первый аргумент конструктора, а `alias` второй?

Хорошо, но что если я ещё захочу дать значение по умолчанию:

```
public class Pet {    
    String name;    
    String alias = "actual pet";
}
```

Какой конструктор должен быть в этом случае? С двумя аргументами или одним? Или может там должен быть конструктор по умолчанию без аргументов? А что если я в конструкторе ещё хочу произвести трансформацию этой строки, чтобы она удовлетворяла системе (например добавить префикс).

Код должен однозначно описывать желаемое вами поведение, компьютеры, к сожалению, ещё не могут додумать за нас, чего мы хотим.

Comment: Конструктор класса к полям не имеет никакого отношения, какой хотите такой конструктор и создавайте, за исключением, если у вас конструктор с аргументами в родительском классе, то необходимо вызвать `super()` из конструктора класса наследника.

Answer (score 0):

Так как у вас поле `name` у класса `Pet` не приватное, то без создания родительского конструктора можно сделать так:

```java
public Cat(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

Если класс `Pet` у вас лежит в другом пакете, тогда поле `name` нужно сделать `protected`:

```java
public class Pet {
    protected String name;
}
```

Comment: Надо сделать приватным.