# Ссылочный тип данных Java

Tags: java

Создается класс Node, и в этом классе поле с типом данных Node.

- Я не понимаю как это работает?
- Как внутри класса тип данных этого же класса, он же еще не создан, и как это в памяти компьютера будет при создании объекта?

```
public static class Node {
        private Node prev;
        private String value;
        private Node next;
    }
```

Comment: Вы буквально спрашиваете нас: `Я не понимаю как это работает?` -- какого ответа вы ожидаете? :)  В показанном коде работать особо нечему.

Comment: а что неясно? Объект класса можно создать из самого  класса, это нормально.

Comment: Для того чтобы создать экземпляр класса надо использовать [конструктор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1307735/204920). Вот так это и работает. Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Answer (score -1):

при создании объекта этого класса полям будут присвоены значения null