# Работа с конструктором в JAVA

Tags: java, ооп, http, конструктор

В Java при создании нового объекта класса мы передаем параметры которые конструктор установит для свойств класса.

**Пример:**

Мое приложение отправило GET запрос и получило данные о погоде, город, температура сегодня, температура завтра, скорость ветра, пусть их будет 15 или 20. В случае если получены все параметры, конструктор эти значения присвоит в свойства(переменные). В случае если ничего не получено я могу создать еще один конструктор и написать логику поведения для этого сценария. Но что делать если один или несколько параметров получить не удалось? К примеру не удалось получить скорость ветра или скорость ветра и температуру на завтра и так далее. Как мне использовать конструктор в данной ситуации?

Comment: Просто определите логику что если какой-то параметр не пришел присвойте ему значение по умолчанию и при выводе там в какую небуть таблицу проверяйте что если значение пустое отобразить прочерк например

Answer (score 0):

Создайте конструктор по умолчанию и сеттеры. Конструктор по умолчанию - это который без аргументов, у него пустые скобки (). Он создает объект с неинициализированными полями. Допустим, у вас класс Weather. И у вас уже есть конструктор с аргументами. Добавляете рядом пустой конструктор по умолчанию:

```
public Weather(){
}
```

Сеттеры - это методы вида

```
void setTemperature(double temp){
    this.temp = temp;
}
```

Конструкторов у вас тогда будет несколько. В Java это нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема имеет множество решений. Я бы это так сделал:

1. Все примитивные поля класса `Wheather` заменил бы на ссылочные. `int` -> `Integer`, `double` -> `Double` и так далее.
2. Написал бы только один конструктор, куда передаётся все ваши 15 или 20 полей.
3. Если у меня к примеру, параметр №12 не пришёл в гет-запросе, я бы передал в конструктор `null` ссылку. `null` - отличное зарезервированное значение.

Comment: С null вообще лучше не работать, можно об этом почитать хорошие статьи "почему null - это плохо".

Comment: @Blacit возможно вы правы, но когда упоминаете название статьи, будет здорово если вы ссылку прикрепите. Потому что я могу неверно загуглить.

Answer (score 0):

> Как мне использовать конструктор в данной ситуации?

Конструктор можно использовать с помощью оператора `this()` или `super()`. Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/890311/204920) есть описание как и почему использовать эти операторы для вызова конструктора с *необходимым* количеством параметров.

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам решить проблему, то ему надо поставить галочку. Галочка и голос "за" находится слева от ответа.