# java, вызов конструктора из конструктора c параметрами

Tags: java

Изучаю конструкторы, пытаюсь решить задачу. Мне надо переписать конструктор без параметров, что бы он вызывал второй конструктор с параметрами.

```
class Hero {
    private String name;
    private int hp;

    public Hero(String name, int hp) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hp = hp;
    }

    public Hero() {
        name = "Paratrooper";
        hp = 100;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }
}
```

пример выполнения тестов

вызов `new Hero().getName()` возвращает **Paratrooper**;
вызов `new Hero("Stranger", 50).getName()` возвращает **Stranger**.

пытаюсь сделать вот так

```
public Hero() {
        this(name,hp);
        name = "Paratrooper";
        hp = 100;
    }
```

вываливается ошибка

> error: cannot reference name before supertype constructor has been
> called this(name,hp);

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов конструктора из другого конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890152/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте написать конструктор так:

```java
public Hero() {
    this("Paratrooper", 100);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я правильно понимаю логику? По умолчанию он выведет уже инициализированные данные, а при явном указании переменных выведет Конкретные значение?

Comment: Да, `"Paratrooper"` и `100` это по сути значения по-умолчанию. Если вызовете конструктор без аргументов `new Hero()`, то объект будет с этими значениями.

Comment: Данный код, который я привел в ответе, можно читать так: *"при вызове конструктора без аргументов `new Hero()`, вызвать уже существующий конструктор с соответствующими значениями: `new Hero("Paratrooper", 100)`"*. Преимущество такого подхода в том, что если у вас будет какая-то логика в основном конструкторе, эта же логика автоматически распространится и на второй констуктор. Не нужно будет дублировать логику в двух разных местах.